# How to filter by 3 filters?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, function

Right now i have a function to identify which filter has been inputted by the user. Here is how my current code works:

### BACKGROUND

- Currently i have 3 blanks, which are *festivalId*, *startTime* and *endTime*.
- User can choose to either filter by either 1 of the 3 blanks(meaning filter by festivalId, or by startTime, or by endTime).
- They can also choose to filter by 2 blanks(meaning filter by festivalId and startTime or festivalId and endTime, *but my current code cannot support filter by startTime and endTime*)

### PROBLEM

- So currently, what i want to do is that i wish to filter by 3 blanks(meaning filter by festivalId, startTime and endTime), also.......
- i want to filter by startTime and endTime, but my current code can't do it.

Can anybody give me guidance to this? I have tried to attempt it(which are the codes that i have commented out), but it broke the entire function.

Here is my current code:

```js
   // retrieve data from PerformanceWithPopularity Table
    function getPopularity(festivalId, startTime, endTime, page = 0, pageSize = 5, callback) {
        let whereClause;
        let i = 1;
        const values = [];
        if (!festivalId && !startTime && !endTime) { whereClause = '' }
        // else if (!festivalId && startTime && endTime) {
        //     whereClause = 'WHERE'
        //     whereClause += `startTime >= $${i++} AND endTime < $${i++}`;
        //     values.push(parseInt(startTime));
        //     values.push(parseInt(endTime));
        // }
        else {
            whereClause = 'WHERE'
            if (festivalId) {
                whereClause += ` festivalId = $${i++}`;
                values.push(parseInt(festivalId));
            }
            if (startTime) {
                whereClause += festivalId ? ` AND startTime >= $${i++}` : ` startTime >= $${i++}`;
                values.push(parseInt(startTime));
            }
            if (endTime) {
                whereClause += festivalId ? ` AND endTime < $${i++}` : ` endTime < $${i++}`;
                values.push(parseInt(endTime));
            }
            // if (festivalId && startTime && endTime) {
            //     whereClause += `festivalId = $${i++} AND starTime >= $${i++} AND endTime < $${i++}`;
            //     values.push(parseInt(festivalId));
            //     values.push(parseInt(startTime));
            //     values.push(parseInt(endTime));
            // }
        }
        let limitoffsetClause = `LIMIT $${i++} OFFSET $${i++}`
        values.push(parseInt(pageSize));    //Limit = pageSize
        values.push(parseInt(page) * parseInt(pageSize));   //offset = page * pageSize
        const query = `SELECT * FROM PerformanceWithPopularity ${whereClause} ${limitoffsetClause}`;
        const client = connect();
        client.query(query, values, function (err, rows) {
            console.log(query)
            client.end();
            callback(err, rows);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to start filtering the result set with `WHERE 1 = 1` in order to avoid unnecessary conditioning in your code. Also, looking at your code, you might be missing some spaces between keywords in your query. Instead of using `parseInt` you might try prefixing your variable with `+` sign, it should also get you a numeric representation of your variable. One last thing, if you have `startTime` and `endTime` as `DateTime` in the database you might need to get the parameter `DateTime` representation instead of its numeric value, but I'll suppose you're aware of that and you have it as Unix timestamp in your database. So, check if the following function works any better:

```
function getPopularity(festivalId, startTime, endTime, page = 0, pageSize = 5, callback) {

    let query = 'SELECT * FROM PerformanceWithPopularity WHERE 1 = 1 ';

    let ordinal = 1;
    let parameters = [];

    if (festivalId) {
        query += ` AND festivalId = $${ordinal++} `;
        parameters.push(+festivalId);
    }

    if (startTime) {
        query += ` AND startTime >= $${ordinal++} `;
        parameters.push(+startTime);
    }

    if (endTime) {
        query += ` AND endTime <= $${ordinal++} `;
        parameters.push(+endTime);
    }

    if (pageSize) {
        query += ` LIMIT $${ordinal++} `;
        parameters.push(+pageSize);
    }

    const offset = (+page) * (+pageSize);
    if (offset) {
        query += ` OFFSET $${ordinal++} `;
        parameters.push(offset);
    }

    const client = connect();
    client.query(query, parameters, function (err, rows) {
        console.log(query);
        client.end();
        callback(err, rows);
    });
}
```